# Why does my Xcode Swift app crash when I make a call to webView.load when I use a Development build?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, webkit

I have an application with a simple view controller that just loads a web page using a WKWebView (import WebKit). This is the code I am using:

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
if let url = URL(string: webPageString) {
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
}
```

This implementation works great when I am debugging on a Simulator. But if I do a 'Development' build and push is to users, then it crashes as soon as it switches to this view controller.

While I was looking for a solution, I found that this could be due to the Data Detectors. So I unchecked all of them, but this didn't change the result.

[image]

Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Comment: If you use your own real device, do you have an error message?

Comment: Without the error it’s impossible to pinpoint what is going wrong, as your code doesn’t show any oddities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to repeat this problem while connected to the debugger. I got the following error message:

> Could not instantiate class named WKWebView because no class named
>   WKWebView was found; the class needs to be defined in source code or
>   linked in from a library (ensure the class is part of the correct
>   target)’

To resolve the error, all you need to do is add the WebKit framework to your Xcode project. This can be done by following these steps:

1. In the project navigator, select your project.
2. Next, select the target and choose the Build Phase tab.

[image]

3. Under the Link Binary with Libraries section, click the + button.
4. Key in 'webkit' and then add the WebKit framework.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What is the message in the console after crash?

Inside what method do you call `webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))` ?

Looks like you have crash because `webView == nil`. You should call `webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))` only after/inside `viewDidLoad()` method has been called in that UIViewController. It is because all `IBOutlet` views are connected not instantly after instantiating `UIViewController`, but after `viewDidLoad()` call.